# How accuracy calculated for train data is used for evaluating test data in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

In tensorflow the model is created with training data but i want to  know how is the test data are evaluated with accuracy calculated with training data.

```
     correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1),tf.argmax(y_train, 1))
     # Calculate accuracy
     accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
     print "Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x1: X_test, y1: y_test})
```

correct_prediction is done with training data and accuracy.eval() is used to pass test data set.
Please explain how this is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TensorFlow you create a graph, where data flows between nodes, from inputs to outputs.

Let's take a simple example, MNIST. Here are the **TensorFlow nodes**:

- inputs:

  - batch of 28x28 images: `images` of shape `[batch_size, 28, 28, 1]`
  - label of the image: `labels` of shape `[batch_size, 10]`
- outputs:

  - predictions of your network `pred`, of shape `[batch_size, 10]`
  - accuracy of the model: `accuracy`, shape `[]` (scalar)

Here is the graph:

```
         images
           |
         (CNN)
           |
  labels  pred
       \   |
        \  |
  correct_prediction
           |
        accuracy
```

---

The two inputs nodes are `tf.placeholder`, which means that you need to manually enter values in them.

Depending on whether you are training or testing the model, you can feed:

- **for training**: feed `images` and `labels` with two numpy arrays `X_train` and `y_train` of corresponding shape, from your data
- **for testing**: feed `images` and `labels` with two numpy arrays `X_test` and `y_test` which are the **test data**

With this architecture, the **same graph** is used both for training and testing.

---

The difference is that:

- during training, you will likely run the train operation `sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={images: X_train, labels: y_train})`
- during testing, you no longer train the model and just compute the accuracy: `sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={images: X_test, labels: y_test})`

Comment: should we not send the test data into the model? just with accuracy op the data is classified ?

Comment: You send the test data into the model using `feed_dict={images: X_test, labels: y_test}`